# Necessity of declaring dependencies in child java module pom

Tags: maven, build, dependencies

Is it necessary to declare dependencies at child's pom.xml when they are present in parent's pom at  (or ) section? Are they inherited?

Comment: An edit to this question would make it clearer to others.  Looks like there's a typo.

Answer (score 2):

The fallowing elements from the parent POM are inherited by the children pom's:

- Dependencies
- Plugin executions
- Plugin configurations
- Other misc. elements (e.g SCM settings, developers, reports)

For more info see: [Pom Inheritance](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance)

So in your case you don't need to declare again the dependencies in the child pom.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know anything about <depdndencyManagement> section? Are dependencies is inherited from it?

Comment: @psed the dependencyManagement element is inherited by the child pom's. This is quite useful to declare the dependency's and their versions here and than later one reference them in the child POM's dependency section without specifying the version. This way you can use the same dependency consistently in the child POM and when you update the version of the dependency you only need to change it in one place (in the parent POM dependency section).

Comment: So, using <dependencyManagement> section in parent pom requires declaring dependencies in child pom? The only difference (with <depndencies>) - <version> is inherited?

Comment: @psed If you declare dependencies in the `<dependencyManagement>` section, you still need to declare them in the `<dependencies>` section. Also both the `<dependencyManagement>` and the `<dependencies>` sections are inherited to the child POM's.

Comment: If you are declaring a dependency in the `<dependencies>` section that has already been declared in the `<dependencyManagement>` section you may omit the `<version>` tag (since it's know from the `<dependencyManagement>` section).